# Visual Studio 2015 Android Designer not opening

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, designer

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and wanted to write a Xamarin Android App. Therefore I created a layout file with  the extension axml. However when double clicking on the file the designer does not open. The only thing I see is the axml file. This is strange since I have seen a few examples where the designer is used.

This is what I am using:

- Android SDK Tooks 25.2.5
- Android SDK Platform tools 25.0.3
- SDK Platform for Android 6.0 (API 23)
- Visual Studio 2015
- jdk 1.7.5_55

I also did a right click -> view designer on the axml file. Next there is a message popin up saying something like: *The document ...axml is already open. Do you want to close it?* However neither clicking *Yes* nor *No* opens the designer. Simply nothing happens.

I created the *.xaml* file with Visual Studio by right-clicking on the *layout* folder in the Android project saying *Add->New Item* and next selecting a new layout file from the list view. So pretty much standard I guess.

Here is the content of the xaml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</LinearLayout>
```

I didn't change something in the file after Visual Studio created it for me. But maybe something is missing in the template. There is a [walkthrough guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/designer_overview/designer_walkthrough/) which I repeated to make sure I haven't done something wrong the first time. However no success so far.

Comment: how did you create/add the layout file to your project? what is the content of the axml file? it wount show in design view if there are invalid descriptions in the file.

Comment: If you do right-click > Open With... > Android Layout file, does it still not display the designer?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Right click -> Open with -> Android Layout file just shows an error message which says: _The file cannot be opnened with the selected editor. Please choose another editor._